# Initializing Controls in NSPanel

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller, nspanel

I've got an NSPanel in my app that I use as a data export feature.

How do I initialize the controls in the panel when it's initially displayed? (i.e. using NSDefaults). There doesn't seem to be an event that fires when the window/panel opens where I can restore the default settings (basically just restoring the value of an NSPopupButton).

Currently, I'm opening the panel using '[NSApp beginSheet...]' in my App Delegate class. Should I be using an NSWindowController subclass instead?

Comment: How is this `NSPanel` coming into existence? For example, is it stored in your main .nib file, or in a .nib file that your App Delegate is loading on demand, or are you creating it programmatically, or...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't subclass the `NSWindowController`, simply subclass the `NSPannel` itself.

**ExportPanel.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface ExportPanel : NSPanel {

}

@end
```

**ExportPanel.m**

```
#import "ExportPanel.h"

@implementation ExportPanel

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialize here
}

@end
```

Comment: Great, Thanks! That fixed it - obvious when you see it!!